# Additional swap created on a new partition gets removed on reboot

Tags: reboot, swap, lvm, rhel-5

I have created a new swap volume using logical volume management tool on RHEL.
Suppose the volume is /dev/rootvg/swap2

I did `mkswamp /dev/rootvg/swap2`
and then `swapon /dev/rootvg/swap2` when listing swap space, using `swapon -s` - i see my new swap space.

However this gets removed the time the server is restarted or if I do a `swapoff -a` and then a `swapon -a`. What is missing. Am I to make a manual entry to `/etc/fstab` ? If so how does it look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, put it in **/etc/fstab**, like so:

```
/dev/rootvg/swap2           none        swap        sw          0 0
```